# Multiple data types in a column in R

Tags: r, types, aggregate

I am trying to aggregate a numeric column (A) by another column (B) that has two data types, character and numeric. When I aggregate I am not getting the total sum. I presume the numeric values in B are being changed to scientific notation and getting aggregated at that level and not at the actual numeric value.

I am not sure if that is the case but the output is not correct.
Any workarounds or solutions to this?

Comment: Could you please add some example data from your dataset. It will be easier to understand your problem.

Comment: Kindly provide the reproducible example.

Comment: Column A - {1,4,134,44,298,42}
Column B - {"abc","123","hgj","123","uy8","123"}
Now when I aggregate (sum) by B - all the character factors have the correct sum(A) but the integer factor ("123") is not giving the correct output - either the output is 4 or 44 or 42 and not 90. Let me know if you need any additional info

Comment: Please refer to this link and reframe your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not very clear. However, see the following example if it solves your purpose.

```
df<-structure(list(A = c(1, 4, 134, 44, 298, 42), B = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("123", "abc", "hgj", "uy8"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("A", "B")) 


aggregate(A~B,df,sum)
    B      A
    1 123  90
    2 abc   1
    3 hgj 134
    4 uy8 298
```